# MapFragment inside Fragment only works on rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I have a problem with MapFragment. The problem is the map works first time i open fragment, but when I leave it (I have sidebar menu) and come back - the screen is just white. But then if i rotate my phone the map shows up.
From debug I can see that this happens when I either enter first time or rotate, but it doesn't happen when I come back to fragment.

```
02-13 08:27:37.263: I/dalvikvm-heap(4553): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.106MB for 4194320-byte allocation
02-13 08:27:37.283: D/dalvikvm(4553): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 18% free 23629K/28748K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
02-13 08:27:37.323: D/dalvikvm(4553): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4356K, 21% free 19534K/24648K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
```

Here is java code for fragment onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootView != null) {
        Log.d("map","rootView != null");
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            Log.d("map","parent != null");
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try {
        Log.d("map","inside try");
        rootView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        setupGmap();
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        Log.d("map","inside catch");
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

In XML:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:name="pl.szymonmaslanka.qrapp.MapFragment" />
```

To add more clearness what happens:
Open app, click map in menu - map shows up correctly -> move to another menu item -> click again map menu - white screen istead of map -> rotate phone - map magically appears.

Cheers

Comment: below is your sloution check it...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
         />
```

and override method OnDestroyView and Just put this code on OnDestroyView()

```
public void onDestroyView() 
 {
    super.onDestroyView(); 
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```